# Reading dynamic values using ConfigurationServices() in Java

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If I have one key value defined in local.properties :
myKey= myValue {0} and {1} fetch from dynamically.

I have tried using getConfigurationService().getConfiguration().getString(myKey, valueFor{0} passed here ,valuefor{1} passed here) in my java class.

But it is not picking up values {0} ,{1} values.
Any lead ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the `Configuration.getString(String key, String defaultValue)` API:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

The `key` argument is for the key in the properties file.
The `defaultValue` is for the default value to use if the key does not exist in the property file.

Scenario 1:

- Properties file has: sample.key=sampleValue1 sampleValue2
- `getString("sample.key", "hello")` will return `sampleValue1 sampleValue2`

Scenario 2:

- Properties file does not have sample.key
- `getString("sample.key", "hello")` will return `hello`